How can one abort a shutdown initiated by VirtualBox on a Windows guest?
A shutdown initiated by VirtualBox on a Windows guest via:

How can one abort a shutdown initiated by VirtualBox on a Windows guest?

You cannot because it is instant. Its the same as pressing the powerbutton on your real computer. You can't stop that either. But you should be able to change "action that is executed when the power button is pressed in Power Management settings" to disable this.

@LPChip thanks, what do you mean by instant?

Once you press ok, it immediately sends that signal to its target, and the OS will then without delay perform the shutdown, similarly as when you do it on your own pc. With the command shutdown -s there is a default delay of 30 seconds to where shutdown -a can be performed. This is not possible when the shutdown signal is transferred from the power button or VirtualBox.

If you have pressed OK, the dialog vanishes, and now the OS is still running, and you want to stop that, well.... if the OS is not shutting down, then it likely tried to do a shutdown but something prevented it, and it no longer will shutdown. This can be having a text document open that is not saved. You get asked if you want to save, but you press cancel instead. The shutdown is aborted. Note that there's no guarantee that this works in all versions of windows.

@LPChip Sometimes the  OS is not shutting down indeed. Or sometimes it takes 2 to 10 seconds for Windows to log off between the shutdown: I was hoping to abort during these 2 to 10 seconds.

You can make sure the OS is not responding to that signal to force using a normal shutdown method. Then you can add a delay, so you can use shutdown -a to abort.

@DrMoishePippik One needs to click on OK to initiate the shutdown by VirtualBox, so the cancel isn't an option anymore as the dialog box closes.

VTC: what's unclear?

@LPChip can you please post your comments as an answer?

I see you already posted an answer. I've voted that one up. Don't feel the need to make a separate answer with basically the same content. :)

If you have those 2-10 seconds and the VM is responsive, have you tried the standard abort command shutdown /a?


How can one abort a shutdown initiated by VirtualBox on a Windows guest?

According to the comments, it is not possible to abort a shutdown initiated by VirtualBox on a Windows guest:


Once you press ok, it immediately sends that signal to its target, and the OS will then without delay perform the shutdown, similarly as when you do it on your own pc. With the command shutdown -s there is a default delay of 30 seconds to where shutdown -a can be performed. This is not possible when the shutdown signal is transferred from the power button or VirtualBox. 
LPChip  Commented7 hours ago
If you have pressed OK, the dialog vanishes, and now the OS is still running, and you want to stop that, well.... if the OS is not shutting down, then it likely tried to do a shutdown but something prevented it, and it no longer will shutdown. This can be having a text document open that is not saved. You get asked if you want to save, but you press cancel instead. The shutdown is aborted. Note that there's no guarantee that this works in all versions of windows. 
– LPChip
Commented7 hours ago 


